# Taxi in Bangkok booked via ride-share apps, the price is predetermined, why do they run the meter?

Tags: thailand, taxis, fares, bangkok

Why do taxi drivers booked via ride-share applications (e.g. Grab) start the meter at the beginning of the ride, even though the price is predetermined via the ride-share application in Bangkok, Thailand?

Example: price in red from the meter on the left, and Grab price on the right on the phone, at the end of a taxi ride (I used JustGrab). Typically, the price on the meter is less than the price on Grab. Taxi drivers will charge the Grab price.

[image]

According to https://help.grab.com/passenger/th-th/360001800748-%E0%B8%82%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AD%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%95%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%82%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87-JustGrab-GrabCar-%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B0-GrabTaxi ([mirror](http://archive.is/bLlKo)), the price of the ride for JustGrab is fixed (i.e., not metered):

[image]

Comment: Did you pay the Grab price or the metered price?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica grab

Comment: Has there been a case where they charge the meter price? Maybe they charge the higher price or the lower price of the two?

Comment: @Daniil haven't seen that happened yet. grab is quite overpriced! I wonder the same as you. But according to grab, one should pay the grab price (since that's the price that the passenger and the driver agreed on)

Comment: Is the Grab price prepaid on a card, with the driver getting the money from Grab?

Comment: @WeatherVane Paid via card through grab, but not prepaid. Sometimes the taxi driver asks for Cash's for tolls though (otherwise the taxi driver will manually add the toll fare in grab)

Comment: Does the grab payment go directly to the driver?  Maybe they will keep the 322 from grab, and tell their boss or the tax authorities that they only collected the meter fare of 181.

Comment: @NateEldredge idk, that's a possibility. But Grab seems quite large to be ignored by the tax police.

Comment: I seem to recall that they have to turn the meter on, even if using Grab, to demonstrate that they are working and that the taxi is occupied.